# MSysGit console and non latin filenames

Tags: msysgit, msys, non-latin

I have install msysgit.
But when I run Git Bash Console I can not input non latin charachers and non latin filenames are displayed as questuion marks.
Is there any way to make console undertand non latin characters.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you still want an answer for this?